# When converting a string of numbers to a float ..why do I just get the first digit?

Tags: php, string

I am aware that the question has been posted before.  Someone had the same problem as me and he fixed it with correcting his encode style.  No further details were given.  I am using UTF-8 .  I am using windows 10 .  My code and with results in the comments follows.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$nickp[0] = trim($nickp[0]);
$nickp[1] = trim($nickp[1]);
$nickp[2] = trim($nickp[2]);


echo"<br>";
echo"var dump on nickp";
echo"<br>";
var_dump($nickp);  //      returns array(3) { [0]=> string(459) "15336.50 " [1]=> string(36) "" [2]=> string(0) "" }
echo"<br>";


echo"here is a print r..";
echo"<br>";
print_r($nickp);
echo"<br>";



$nickpf = (float)$nickp;

echo"<br>";
echo"var dump on float nickpf";
echo"<br>";
var_dump($nickpf);  // returns float(1)
echo"<br>";

echo"<br>";
echo"var dump on float nickpf[0]";
echo"<br>";
var_dump($nickpf[0]);  returns NULL
echo"<br>";


echo"just nickpf";
echo"<br>";
echo $nickpf;  // returns 1
echo"<br>";

$nickpf =( $nickpf -13380.50);

echo"just nickpf birth year";
echo"<br>";
echo $nickpf;// returns - 13379.50
echo"<br>";
```

Comment: Can you just put the value of `$nickp` in a comment in the above question?

Comment: It seems that your are asking why `(float)$array` is 1. If so, see [floatval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php#refsect1-function.floatval-returnvalues). *Empty arrays return 0, non-empty arrays return 1.*

Comment: 15336.50 is the string I want as a float

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for

```
$nickp = ["15336.50", "12312.11", "123123.22"]; // example

$nickp[0] = trim($nickp[0]);
$nickp[1] = trim($nickp[1]);
$nickp[2] = trim($nickp[2]);


echo floatval(preg_replace('/[[:^print:]]/', "", $nickp[0]));
```

Comment: interesting floatval($nickp[0]) returns 0   which means I have hidden characters in front of string numbers.

Comment: @sonny, thats why I asked to print the result in my first comment. I clearly doubted, when you mentioned `returns array(3) { [0]=> string(459) "15336.50 "`. I have edited my answer, Check that

Comment: still returns 0.  There is a hidden line return and other hidden crap as style background that can change colours.